# Why don't I see the LOCAL cache option on AWS CodeBuild?

Tags: aws-codebuild

Any idea why I don't see the Local option like it's mentioned [in the doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-caching.html)?

[image: AWS CodeBuild Screenshot]

Comment: Which instance type are you using? Local cache is not available on all instance types.

Comment: Thanks. I found out that using the 72CPU instances you can't use local caches. Makes sense, but they don't mention it in any of the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Subin Mathew. I also found out that the local cache is only available upto 8 vCPU instances. The AWS docs don't mention it anywhere.

Comment: It is called out in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-caching.html#caching-local-cli (text right above this section). Agree it could have been better surfaced, especially in the UI console.